# how to get xpath from this xml structure

Tags: xml, xpath

im trying to get the integer value from the following xml structure (its only a part of the file)

I need to get the value of 00/pkw/diesel/pm0/integer but i don't know how to search after this...

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>00</key>
<dict>
    <key>pkw</key>
    <dict>
        <key>gas</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>diesel</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ohne</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm01</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm0</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm1</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm2</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm3</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm4</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>pm5</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>otto</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

May you have an idea?

Regards
float

EDIT:

That works correctly:

```
/plist/dict/key[.=01]/following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='pkw']/following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='diesel']//following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='pm01']//following-sibling::*[1]
```

But i don't know if this is good xpath syntax ;-)

Comment: Who came up with this XML spec? The person who came up with this really doesn't have the fainest idea how to search it... I guess it's read only sequentially, by an specialized software.

Comment: well it's a plist file from an iphone app for finedust calculation. i wan't to use it in android.

Comment: The solution might be:

    /plist/dict/key[.=01]/following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='pkw']/following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='diesel']//following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='pm01']//following-sibling::*[1]

Comment: Nasty way would be //key/following-sibling::integer[1] but the way the file is all over the place I wouldn't be confident that this would work in all scenarios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is the following:

```
/plist/dict/key[. = '00']/../dict/key[. = 'pkw']/../dict/key[. = 'diesel']/../dict/key[. = 'pm0']/following-sibling::integer[1]
```

and you can see the result [here](http://xmltools.dk/tQAcADA6). As you can see it is a pretty silly expression. I could use `following-sibling::...` more extensive, but it depends on how precise the structure of the xml is.

*Addition to your question:*

```
/plist/dict/key[.=01]/following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='pkw']/following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='diesel']//following-sibling::*[1]/key[.='pm01']//following-sibling::*[1]
```

you should replace `*`´s with the name of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each key `(THE_KEY = 00, pwk, diesel, ...)` with `dict[key/text()='THE_KEY']` in your "example xpath":

```
00/pkw/diesel/pm0/integer
```

An example result should be:

```
dict[key/text()='00']/dict[key/text()='pkw']/
```